# How Do I Apply CSS after Using .load()?

Tags: jquery, css, load

how do I apply CSS to an element AFTER the element has been loaded using .load()? Here a dummy version of what I'm working with.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.link").on("click", function() {
        var Selected = $(this).attr("ID");
        $("#container").load(Selected + ".php");
        $("#box").css("background-color", "red");
        return false;
        });
});
```

Jquery loads #box into #container as intended using the .load() function, but the line with .css() doesn't work. When I click on the a.link to trigger the events, #box's background color turns red for a split second then reverts back. Anyone know how I can keep it red?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load function have a callback. Use it.

```
$("#container").load(Selected + ".php", function(){
  $("#box").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! I'm new to JQUery and been trying to find out how to do this for over a day!